# Error: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"

Tags: android, apache-cordova, xcode, ionic3, cordova-plugin

Camaradas,

Estou tendo um problema ao rodar "ionic cordova run android --target=nome do meu device".

O emulador abre normalmente com o Nexus 5X API 26 porém antes de iniciar totalmente o emulador ele retorna esse erro:

//Error: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device:

Error: adb: Command failed with exit code 255

Error output:
error: protocol fault (no status)//

Eu mudei de computador recentemente, onde instalei o Ubuntu 16.04 e rodei o meu código que antes rodava normalmente na máquina antiga.

Alguém consegue ajudar?

Obrigado